# Export Metadata from the componentspace IdP

Tags: asp.net, metadata, saml

how can i create a idp metadata for sp(tableau server).

I have crated the Idp application using componentspace.

how can i accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the popular IdP's, such as OpenAM, ADFS, Shibboleth... ,  have possibility to generate for you IdP metadata that you can export further to your SP's.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but there is a project in CS under MetaData called ExportMetaData and it's pretty well documented.  Basically you just need to call the application and add the SAML.config location, your certificate name and output file as parameters.